# Is it possible add a texture to a plane in the two-dimensional animation editor?

Tags: image, 2d

So I wanted to make a 2D animation about this specific spite of Mario( made by Nintendo) flying through an obstacle course. I added in a similarly 2D plane, rotated 90 degrees so I could see it from that angle. I was going to add this texture to it, but I didn't know how because I'm a newbie, so I tried out making materials with this texture. I couldn't find out how to add the texture to the material itself, however. So then I tried making nodes work, but to no avail. I have literally no idea how I'm going to do this besides what already failed. The 2D editor has no UV mapper, either. How am I going to add this image to a 2D animation?
[image: This is the texture/sprite/image/PNG I wanted.]

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "the two-dimensional animation editor"?

Answer (score 2):

The 2D animation editor actually is the 3D view editor. The "2D Animation" startup file sets the world to white, adds a grease pencil object, and goes into edit mode. Other than that, it's just a different set of layout tabs for Blender.

Go ahead and, in the 2D animation editor tab, orbit around.

In respect to putting an image texture onto a plane, since it is actually the standard 3D space, look for UV and image texture material tutorials.

If you still need help, I might be able to provide a tutorial, but don't worry: There's nothing to be afraid of :)